Title: "IMAP Connection Error: 'Socket error: 0x02: Connection not allowed by ruleset' when using SOCKS5 Proxy in Python"
I'm trying to connect to an IMAP server through a SOCKS5 proxy using Python. However, I keep encountering the error: Socket error: 0x02: Connection not allowed by ruleset. Below is the code I'm using:
import imaplib
import socks
import socket
import ssl
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth

# Proxy configuration
PROXY_HOST = "178.xx.xx.xxx"
PROXY_PORT = 10300
PROXY_USERNAME = "xxx"
PROXY_PASSWORD = "xxx"

# Email configuration
IMAP_SERVER = "imap.gmx.com"
IMAP_PORT = 993
EMAIL = "uhnwlwnosnyu@gmx.com"
PASSWORD = "xxxxx"

def check_proxy_connection():
    session = requests.Session()
    session.proxies = {
        "http": f"http://{PROXY_USERNAME}:{PROXY_PASSWORD}@{PROXY_HOST}:{PROXY_PORT}",
        "https": f"http://{PROXY_USERNAME}:{PROXY_PASSWORD}@{PROXY_HOST}:{PROXY_PORT}"
    }
    try:
        response = session.get("http://api.myip.com", timeout=10)
        response.raise_for_status()
        return response.json()
    except requests.RequestException as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return None

# Check the proxy connection
proxy_response = check_proxy_connection()
if proxy_response:
    print(f"Proxy is working. Response from api.myip.com:\n{proxy_response}")
else:
    print("Proxy is not working. Exiting the script.")
    exit()

# Set up the proxy with authentication
socks.set_default_proxy(
    socks.SOCKS5,
    PROXY_HOST,
    PROXY_PORT,
    username=PROXY_USERNAME,
    password=PROXY_PASSWORD
)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

try:
    # Create an SSL context
    ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()

    # Connect to the IMAP server through the proxy
    imap_client = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(IMAP_SERVER, IMAP_PORT, ssl_context=ssl_context)

    # Login to the email account
    imap_client.login(EMAIL, PASSWORD)
    print("Successfully logged in")

    # List available mailboxes
    status, mailboxes = imap_client.list()
    if status == 'OK':
        print("Available mailboxes:")
        for mailbox in mailboxes:
            print(mailbox.decode())

    # Select the inbox
    imap_client.select('INBOX')

    # Search for emails
    status, messages = imap_client.search(None, 'ALL')
    if status == 'OK':
        message_numbers = messages[0].split()
        print(f"Number of emails in inbox: {len(message_numbers)}")

        # Fetch the latest email
        if message_numbers:
            latest_email_id = message_numbers[-1]
            status, msg_data = imap_client.fetch(latest_email_id, '(RFC822)')
            if status == 'OK':
                print("Latest email fetched successfully")
                # Here you can process the email content if needed
                # raw_email = msg_data[0][1]
                # email_message = email.message_from_bytes(raw_email)
                # ...

except imaplib.IMAP4.error as e:
    print(f"An IMAP error occurred: {e}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")
finally:
    try:
        imap_client.logout()
        print("Logged out and closed the connection")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to close the connection cleanly: {e}")

Error Message:
An unexpected error occurred: Socket error: 0x02: Connection not allowed by ruleset
Steps I've Taken:
Verified that the proxy works by checking the response from http://api.myip.com.
Attempted to connect to the IMAP server through the proxy using imaplib.IMAP4_SSL.

Environment:
Python version: 3.12.3
pysocks library for proxy handling
IMAP server: imap.gmx.com
Proxy: SOCKS5 with authentication

What could be causing the "Connection not allowed by ruleset" error when connecting through the SOCKS5 proxy?
Are there any additional steps I need to take to properly configure the proxy for IMAP connections?

It sounds like the proxy you're using threw an error because it has rules to prevent connecting to IMAP servers on port 993.  By connecting to api.myip.com, you've only verified that it works on port 80.

what can i do ?

Reconfigure your proxy?  Ask your admin to reconfigure your proxy? Don't use a proxy?  This is between you and your network administrator.

thank can you suggest me any place that can i buy proxy from there for this work

No, that is explicitely off topic for StackOverflow.
